# Python, генерировать случайные значения (дробные) с пользовательским распределением

Tags: python

Имеется таблично заданное кастомное распределение:

```
p = np.array([
    [5,  0.10],
    [7,  0.15],
    [8,  0.25],
    [11, 0.15],
    [13, 0.25],
    [15, 0.10]
])
```

Я хочу генерить случайные числа, типа 7.9235621356, 13.1245235, 9.53456235 и т.д. по одному или сразу списком с задаваемым количеством штук.

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html

Comment: @strawdog он будет мне генерить одно из тех чисел в 0й колонке, мне нужны дробные.

Comment: 1. Можно увидеть ваши попытки решения?
2. Как получается 9.53456235, если 9 нет в распределении?